# Script doesn't act the same when executed alone and through /etc/init.d

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, embedded, sysvinit

I'm struggling a lot with a script behavior i'm unable to understand.
I have a script that is being called in a process i created in the init.d folder.

So at startup the script is executed but there is a specific command in it that is left immediatly after it was launch but the only way to quit this command (corresponding to a program) is to push the"enter" button, so i don't understand why the program is left.
And the weird thing is that when i manually execute the script, the behavior correspond to what i expect so i'm very confused.

To make it more understundable this is what happen:

1. "/etc/init.d/S60Startup.sh" is executed at startup
2. "/etc/init.d/S60Startup.sh" execute "data.sh" in a subprocess.
3. "data.sh" execute "nfcDemoApp"---> "nfcDemoApp" is executed and immediatly left while the only way to leave it is to push "enter" button.
4. When "data.sh" is manually executed, "nfcDemoApp" doesn't stop right after it was executed and behave as expected.

Has anyone observed this kind of behavior?

thank you in advance

Comment: Check the error log. Hint interactive/non interactive shell.

Comment: A related hint: Different environments.

Comment: "left" is ambiguous here, do you mean "leave, exit, go away" or do you mean "stay, remain"? Does the program exit or does it never finish?

Comment: What is nfcDemoApp? Did you write it? It sounds like it detects of it is running in an interactive shell or not and exits if it is not.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your answers.
By "left" I meant "exit".
And "nfcDemoApp" was written in C by the chip supplier which is NXP.
So, you mean that the program should be forced to be launch in an interactive shell or I will keep having this issue forever?

Comment: @terdon I ended up moving "nfcDemoApp" in another script and i'm calling it through the main script. The behavior is still the same.
Then i decided to add an infinite loop right after the "nfcDemoApp" command line and the behavior i exactly the same. "nfcDemoApp exit immediatly after being executed and the script goest right away in the infinite loop, and the script doesn't exit. 
So I don't really understand this interactive/non-interactive shell thing. The program act exactly as i expect, but only if i execute it manually and not automatically at startup.

Comment: There is no "enter" key, since at the time this is run there is no connection to a terminal.

Comment: ... and any read from standard input will immediately return EOF - which will probably be interpreted as an error, if it is checked at all ... you are lucky it didn't go into an infinite loop printing the prompt "hit enter key ..." or something like that :-)

Comment: @MurrayJensen Actually, i need it to stay I an infinite loop and leave it after 30 seconds. "Any read from standard input will return EOF". I don't see the "EOF" when manually executing the script so I doubt that this would be the problem

Comment: @JeremyBoden I said like if I hit "enter" so an "EOL"

Comment: The usual way for a program to wait until someone hits the "enter" key, is to do a read() system call from the standard input in a loop until a "newline" is seen. Since the script is being run in a non-interactive environment, the standard input is likely to be connected to `/dev/null` rather than a so-called "terminal" (some sort of `/dev/ttyXXX` device), so any read will immediately return with the return value being zero. This is usually interpreted as EOF (End Of File).

Comment: ... A lot of code will only check for an error (the return value is negative or -1) and otherwise treat the return value as the number of characters that were read. Since zero was returned, the code will loop indefinitely, re-prompting for input. In your case, it appears that the code does check for zero return, interprets this as EOF, and the program exits (a reasonable thing to do).

Comment: @MurrayJensen thank you, it's clear now!
But actually the "infinite loop" behavior is exactly the one i'm expecting so actually, i still have a problem. Actually this code is completely useless without this inifinite loop.
Does anyone know if there is a way to force the script to run interactively?
I tried "bash -i" but this doesn't work...Also tried to ignore EOF using "export ignoreeof=1" but this doesn't work neither...

Comment: It is not an "infinite loop" - the program is suspended until input is available on standard input and then execution is resumed and the read() system call will return with a positive number of characters that were received - assuming it is "interactive" (i.e. standard input is connected to a "terminal" or "tty"). You could force it to connect to a particular "tty" device with something like this `(stty sane && /bin/bash data.sh) </dev/ttyXX >/dev/ttyXX 2>&1` or you could use `/dev/console`, but this will halt the booting of your system until someone hits enter on that tty or the console.

Comment: (i.e. _don't do that_ - in case it wasn't obvious :-)

Comment: I found an alternative to this behavior that is a big issue for me. I had to modify the source code of the program i'm executing.
I've added the function `sleep()` just before the `getchar()` function so it leaves me an interval i can choose before exiting the program, which is ok for now. I will find another alternative when i have more time. 
Thanks again for helping.